# Applying Field formats to multiple projects

Tags: ms-project, process

As my project develops, I find I am constantly tweaking various fields, views and filters.  Is there a way to apply these tweaks to multiple projects rather than the many sub-projects, one at a time?

Many Thanks,  Rachel.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy custom views, filters, and field definitions between projects using the Organizer.  Open both files and in the file with the customization, File > Info, click Organizer.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, you are right though I can only do this one project at a time rather than apply a modification to a group of projects.  Have I missed something?

Comment: No, each project has its own views, fields etc.  The best I can suggest is the organizer option.  You can certainly open the multiple projects and quickly copy from one to each in turn.

Comment: In the Organizer you can copy a specific project view back to the default file. That makes it available to new project files.